# Want to create a ul li from some comma seperated values

Tags: php, list, html-lists

currently i have some comma seperated values like

"oranges, apples, pies"

and i want to turn those into a list like this

- oranges
- apples
- pies

hope anyone can help me here

Answer (score 8):

```
$data = "oranges, apples, pies";
$data = explode(',', $data);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $data as $item ) {
    echo '<li>', trim($item), '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

---

[sarcasm=on]
For those who are looking for unmaintainable, hard-to-read code with no *complex* stuff like arrays and looping through them (*yeah, I know, string technically is a kind of array, though it's different from what usually is meant with arrays*):

```
$input = 'oranges, apples, pies';
$output = '';

$output = '<ul><li>';
$inputLength = strlen($input);
$skipSpaces = true;
for ( $n = 0; $n < $inputLength; ++$n ) {
    if ( $skipSpaces ) {
        if ( $input[$n] === ' ' ) {
            continue;
        }
        $skipSpaces = false;
    }
    if ( $input[$n] === ',' ) {
        $skipSpaces =  true;
        $output .= '</li><li>';
        continue;
    }
    $output .= $input[$n];
}
$output .= '</li></ul>';

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: You can save yourself the loop: `echo "<li>"; echo implode("</li><li>", explode(',', $data)); echo "</li>";`

Comment: Or.. heck, come to think of it, skip the implode/explode step and simply to a `echo str_replace(',', '</li><li>', $data)`

Comment: Marc B, `str_replace()` and loopless code work well if one does not need to trim values and does not need more *complicated* output (e.g., with links, icons or something else; I usually need more than plain unordered list). Also, if data is being prepared somewhere before outputting, it would make sense to convert list of values to `array` - templates (be it smarty, plain HTML/PHP templates or anything else) don't really need to know that initially data was formatted as CSV.

Answer (score 2):

```
$slist = "oranges, apples, pies";
echo "<ul><li>" . str_replace(", ", "</li><li>", $slist) . "</li></ul>";
```

Comment: sorry, my bad... comma+space should be replaced with it.

Answer (score 1):

Will only add none yet mentioned possibilities:

```
printf(
    '<ul><li>%s</li></ul>',
    implode(
        '</li><li>',
        str_getcsv("oranges, apples, pies")
    )
);
```

though `str_getcsv` is somewhat overkill if you dont have multiple rows and enclosing chars and stuff like that. Can just as well just use `explode` then.

Yet another possibility:

```
echo '<ul>';
$tok = strtok("oranges, apples, pies", ',');
while ($tok !== false) {
    echo '<li>', trim($tok), '</li>';
    $tok = strtok(',');
}
echo '</ul>';
```

And another one:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('ul')
);
foreach(explode(',', 'oranges, apples, pies') as $fruit) {
    $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
        $dom->createElement('li', $fruit)
    );
}
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

And a final one:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startElement('ul');
foreach(explode(',', 'oranges, apples, pies') as $fruit) {
    $writer->writeElement('li', $fruit);
}
$writer->endElement();
```